# Rest API Wordpress 5.8 Sidebars and Widgets

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to get currently used widgets via request:

https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/sidebars .

Based on documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_sidebars_controller it should works, but I'm getting 401 permission needed:

```
{
    "code": "rest_cannot_manage_widgets",
    "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to manage widgets on this site.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}
```

I don't need to edit widgets etc. but only read them via REST API. Is that possible to do that somehow?

**I'm registering sidebars this way:**

```
// If Dynamic Sidebar Exists
if ( function_exists( 'register_sidebar' ) ) {
    // Define Sidebar Widget Area 1
    register_sidebar( array(

        'name'          => esc_html( 'Widget Area 1', 'mydomain' ),
        'description'   => esc_html( 'First Footer Widget Area', 'mydomain' ),
        'id'            => 'widget-area-1',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="%2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h3>',
        'after_title'   => '</h3>',
    ) );
}
```

Comment: Share the code you're using to communicate with the REST API so we can help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to populate your sidebar with some widgets and register it with `show_in_rest` like this:

```php
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Some sidebar name',
    'id' => 'some-sidebar-id',
    ...
    'show_in_rest' => true,
));
```

After that you'll get:

- `/wp-json/wp/v2/sidebars` all sidebars
- `/wp-json/wp/v2/sidebars/some-sidebar-id` a specific sidebar
- `/wp-json/wp/v2/widgets` all widgets
- `/wp-json/wp/v2/widgets?sidebar=some-sidebar-id` widgets from a sidebar
- `/wp-json/wp/v2/widgets/some-widget-id` a specific widget

Docs:

- [register_sidebar parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_sidebar/#parameters) (`'show_in_rest' => true`)
- [widgets Wordpress 5.8 changes](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/06/29/rest-api-changes-in-wordpress-5-8/) (`'show_instance_in_rest' => true`)